Error al consultar la base de datos PHP
Hola buenas noches estoy tratando de consultar la información que tengo en la base de datos y arroja el siguiente error:
"Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\laragon\www\login_registro\login.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\login_registro\login.php(25): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\login_registro\login.php on line 25"
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
header('Location: index.php');
}

$errores = '';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$usuario = strtolower($_POST['usuario']);
$password = $_POST['password'];
//$password = hash('sha512', $password);

try {
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login_practica', 'root', 'a123');
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //header('Location: contenido.view.php');
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'La conexion ha fallado' .$e->getMessage();;
}


$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND 
pass = password');

$statement->execute(array(
    ':usuario' => $usuario, 
    ':password' => $password
));

$resultado = $statement->fetch();

var_dump($resultado);

   

if($resultado !== false){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;

    //header('Location: index.php');
   echo "Datos correctos";
}else{
    $errores .= '<li>Datos Incorrectos</li>';
}

}

require 'views/login.view.php';

?>



En la parte donde haces la consulta
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND pass = password');

Donde pasas el valor de password te faltan los :. La consulta seria asi:
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND pass = :password');


Si, tienes toda la razón, le agradezco mucho por su ayuda: solucionado!!!!

@AndrwSoto Si la respuesta te ha ayudado, favor marcarla como aceptada
